# C# How to Search in Datagridview without Textbox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to search some text in particular column in C#

For example I have three columns : Roll No,Name, Surname

Whenever I type name like "Mohan" in Datagridview ,I want to see data having Name as Mohan.

Most important thing is I don't want to use textbox to search,I need to type letters in Datagridview and search.

My Datagridview is read only,so whatever I type in Datagridview,no cell will be edited.

Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what do you mean *type letters in DataGridView*? Where in the grid do you want to type?

Comment: Sounds like you want to hook every alphanumeric key in the control, which is a very non-intuitive UI.

Comment: In Datagridview,I want to type.

Comment: What is the SelectionMode?

Comment: What you are trying to do violates user expectations. Nobody expects to search a grid by typing into it, they expect to edit or insert. There is a reason every search you've seen or used is separate from the view of the data.

Answer (score 0):

This code will go through the rows in the `DataGridView` and check the `Name` column for the search value, if found, it will select that row:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in yourGrid.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells["Name"].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
    {
        row.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: where should I write this code and how to set searchValue you specified

Comment: You need to write that code wherever the search is triggered. Do you have a button the user presses to search? If yes, put this code within the button click handler. The `searchValue` will come from wherever the user is putting the search term. Where do you want the user to enter the search term?

Comment: Actually,I don't want to use textbox or any button,I simply want to type anywhere in Datagridview. This is the reason why I am stucked.

Comment: I can help you but first you need to explain something to me: If the user types "John", which column are you going to search? You would need to search every column. Is that ok with you?

Comment: It is ok for me to search in any column or in particular column.What important to me is to search in Datagridview

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I agree with CodingYoshi - you shouldn't do this without providing the appropriate controls. However, I think there is a way to achieve what you're after, so I'll provide you an idea of how to do it.

First, you need to determine in what column do you want to lookup the search term. For this purpose, you set up a handler for the `CellEnter` event and track the `ColumnIndex` of the cell. Of course, if you want to search every cell on every row OR the `SelectionMode` is not `FullRowSelect` you don't need that.

Next, you need a mechanism to follow the keystrokes, so you know what to search for when the user presses Enter.

```
    private void dgv_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        ActiveColumn = e.ColumnIndex;
        SearchTerm = string.Empty;
    }

    private void dgv_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm))
        {
            Lookup(SearchTerm.ToLowerInvariant());
            SearchTerm = string.Empty;
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back && SearchTerm.Length > 0)
        {
            SearchTerm = SearchTerm.Substring(0, SearchTerm.Length - 1);
        }
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            SearchTerm = string.Empty;
        }
        else
        {
            var converter = new KeysConverter();
            var c = Convert.ToChar(converter.ConvertToString(e.KeyData));

            if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
            {
                SearchTerm += c;

                label1.Text = SearchTerm;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Lookup(string what)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            var currentText = row.Cells[ActiveColumn].Value.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();

            if (currentText.Contains(what))
            {
                row.Selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code assumes the `DataGridView` has the focus. If there are other focusable controls on the form, you need to accomodate this, depending on your logic.